# Emgucv how to find multiple similar objects within the same row

Tags: c#, image, emgucv

I am using emguCV with C#. I can find multiple similar object but I only want objects that matches a template image in the same row. Assume all rectangle in image are the same size and shape.

So basically right now i have a template image that is always the left most bounded box and it will match with all objects that are similar, but i only want it on the same row as my ROI.

[what I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5hzp.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.